# How does clicking on a JList item open a new tab in JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a JSplitPane divided verticlly which contains JList on the left hand side and a JTabbedPane on the right hand side.
The JList varaiable is named jlist1 which contains 4 items.
The JTabbedPane has no tabs by default.
I want that whenever a user clicks on  any of the JList item, a new tab should be opened dynamically on the right hand side of JSplitPane(i.e., a new tab opened in JTabbedPane).
I also want to provide a closing button [x] to all dynamically opened tabs.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: It did help to some extent. But I am not able to put the ListSelection event for every JList item. Can u tell me how I can add a listener for every item in JList?  P.s. I am newbie here

Comment: `how I can add a listener for every item in JList?` - the listener does apply to all items. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Lists` for a working example. However, you should not be using a selection listener. If a user uses the keyboard to go from the top item to the bottom item a new tab will be opened for each selection. The normal convention is to use a double click with the mouse or Enter with the keyboard to do processing on the selected item.

Answer (score 2):

> I also want to provide a closing button [x] to all dynamically opened tabs

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html). There is a working example that shows how to do this.

> I want that whenever a user clicks on any of the JList item, a new tab should be opened dynamically

Well any UI should allow the user to either use the mouse or the keyboard to provide an `Action`. So typically when using a `JList` you would use a double click with the mouse or Enter with the keyboard.

Check out [List Action](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/). It is a simple class that allows you to create an `Action` that can be invoked whenever the mouse or keyboard is used.

So in your custom `Action` you would need to add the logic to create a new tab for the selected item in the `JList`. Start with the simple Action provided in the link and add your custom code.

Comment: Thank u, buddy. i still need to work on the "Action" part of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a listener that listens to selection events in jlist. You can achieve this by firing a selection event in JList. 
You could use javax.swing.event
The JTabbedPane should listen to this event, get the object associated with the event and construct a tab in the listener implementation.

Comment: Thank u for your response.Can u pls explain it by giving an example?